# Add live profiling parameters

Tags: mongodb, parameters, profiling

I want to append a slow log parameter to my live MongoDB instance, but I don't want to shut it down, add `--profile --slowtime` parameter, and restart my MongoDB. Is there any way to add parameter while live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable profiling while mongod is running using the mongo shell and the setProfilingLevel command.

```
db.setProfilingLevel(1,20)
```

Will enable profiling with a slowms of 20ms.

For more details see here: [Database Profiler](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler).